# How to check that no ItemizedOverlay is Taped on the MapView?

Tags: android, touch, overlay, android-mapview, tap

I created an MapView with 2 different Overlays. 
One Overlay shows the POIs on the map and the second shows a "bubble" when you click / tab one of the POIs.

Now I want to remove the second overlay when it is visible and no POI is tapped!
I only need to know how to check if I click only the map or one of the POIs??? (also the bubble can be clicked).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, when defining your

```
    public class MyItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<MyObject>
```

you can override

```
    @Override
    protected boolean onTap(final int index) {
        // Called when you tap on an overlay
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTap(GeoPoint p, MapView mapView) {
        // Called when you tap somewhere with no overlay
        // So remove the second overlay here
    }
```

Comment: if you tap on a POI both methods are called! at first onTap(point, map) and as second onTap(index) :) this is the big problem i have

Comment: Yeah that's right. But if you add your bubble in `protected boolean onTap(final int index)` and remove it in `public boolean onTap(GeoPoint p, MapView mapView)` It should be ok. As it's in the same loop, it won't blink. It's exactly what i do in my application (wich have some POI and a bubble when POI's are tapped. But i use a simple view instead of another overlay.).